# Airflow Get value from table in Bigquery and use the return value to pass into next task

Tags: airflow

I am trying to Take data from BigQuery Dataset and pass the result value to bash_command so that it will execute commands to remove files in Cloud storage.

When I execute 'SELECT commandshell_variable_1 FROM sys_process.outbound_flat_file_config where  file_number=1' the result is .....      gsutil rm -r gs://A/loop_member_*.csv

I want to use the result of below and Pass it to bash_command in next task ...
Thank you.

[DAG Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TClaS.jpg)

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='kodz_Automation',
    description='kodz_Automation',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup= False,
    default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS) as dag:

def get_data_from_bq(**kwargs):
    hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    conn = hook.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT commandshell_variable_1 FROM sys_process.outbound_flat_file_config where  file_number=1')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print('result', result)
    return result

fetch_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fetch_data_public_dataset',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_data_from_bq,
    dag=dag
    )
also_run_this = bash_operator.BashOperator(
    task_id='also_run_this',
    bash_command=python_callable
)
```

fetch_data >> also_run_this

Answer (score 0):

To send data from one task to another you can use [Airflow XCOM](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) feature.

Using PythonOperator, the returned value will be stored in XCOM by default, so all you need to do is add a xcom_pull in the BashOperator, something like this:

```
also_run_this = bash_operator.BashOperator(
   task_id='also_run_this',
   bash_command="<you command> {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=[\'fetch_data_public_dataset\']) }}'"
)
```

[Learn more of XCOM here](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-xcom/)

But if you will return a lot of data, I recommend saving this in some storage (like S3, GCS, etc) and then sending the link address to the bash command.